# How to access postgresql DB server that has "too many clients" and kill connections?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, service, connection

I was careless when I made some changes to my C# web service which accesses a postgresql database server at my work, and I forgot to close some connections I made. After testing the service many times over the past few days, I realized too late that I forgot to close my connections and now I can't access the server.

I've googled other solutions but they all involve me changing the max connection size in the postgres.conf file. The problem is that I don't have such a file on my own computer. I'm assuming the conf file is on the original machine that hosts the database server?

Is there any solution to this so that I can access the server again, and kill the old connections, without going to the original host machine of the database?

Comment: The only other option is to connect as the database superuser, which has `superuser_reserved_connections` other users cannot use. Or, if you can, ssh in to the DB server and `kill -TERM` individual PostgreSQL worker backends. In future you can prevent this by setting a connection limit on the user your appserver connects as.

Answer (score 2):

The only other options are:

- to connect as the database superuser, which has `superuser_reserved_connections` other users cannot use; or
- if you can, ssh in to the DB server and `kill -TERM` individual PostgreSQL worker backends. (on windows, that'd be rdp'ing in and using End Process on the backend postgres.exe processes, but it's much harder to pick a safe one to terminate on Windows, you'd want to use Process Explorer to examine the process heirachy and arguments so you can pick a regular backend).

In future you can prevent this by setting a connection limit on the user your appserver connects as; see `ALTER USER`.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just trying to connect over and over again and it eventually let me access the database again. I'm guess maybe some of the connections were automatically killed? I'm not exactly sure what happened.